# get total of ArrayList, grouped according to date using lambda functions in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a model class for Invoice which contains the date on which purchase was made and the price.

```
Class Invoice{
    Date purchaseDate;
    BigDecimal price;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I get the list of invoice which contains all the invoices for the product sold in one month:

```
List<Invoice> invoiceListForMonth;
```

I want to get the total sales done on each day of the month.

```
List<BigDecimal> dayWiseSales;
```

How can I get the data in list using lambda functions with java 8?

Comment: `list.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i.purchaseDate)` would be a good start.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something Like this :

```
List<Invoice> invoiceListForMonth = new ArrayList<>();
//add some data
Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> result =
        invoiceListForMonth.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Invoice::getPurchaseDate
                )).entrySet().stream()//This will return a map of Map<LocalDateTime, List<Invoice>>
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, // to collect with the date
                        e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Invoice::getPrice) //and the sum of
                                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)) // prices
                );
```

---

To understand it better You can separate your work in two steps :

```
Map<LocalDateTime, List<Invoice>> grouping =
        invoiceListForMonth.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Invoice::getPurchaseDate));

Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> result = grouping.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Invoice::getPrice)
                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
        );
```

[**Concrete example demo**](https://ideone.com/oQkZVO)

---

Note I used `LocalDate` from `java.time` API because `Date` is old now and I don't suggest to use it any more.

---

**Edit**

> actually the Invoice class is used in multiple other places so I
>   cannot change it to LocalDate. I tried to implement it using Date but
>   my collection is grouped with date and time. I want to group using
>   date only. Can you suggest something?

Based on your comment you can create your own method which remove the time part from the Date so you can compare only the Date part like so :

```
public static Date getDateWithoutTime(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Then you can make a call thie method in `groupingBy` like so :

```
Map<Date, List<Invoice>> grouping =
        invoiceListForMonth.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        p -> getDateWithoutTime(p.getPurchaseDate())
                ));
Map<Date, BigDecimal> result = grouping.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Invoice::getPrice)
                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
        );
```

---

Note : I strongly don't suggest to use this old API, instead you can move to java.time this will help you a lot.

Comment: actually the Invoice class is used in multiple other places so I cannot change it to LocalDate. I tried to implement it using Date but my collection is grouped with date and time. I want to group using date only. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shall use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`.

To get an overview for each product, you could easy transform your `List<Invoice> invoiceListForMonth` in a correspondending map as follow:

```
final Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> dateBigDecimalMap = listinvoiceListForMonth
               .stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPurchaseDate))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Invoice::getPurchaseDate,
                        Invoice::getPrice,
                        BigDecimal::add));
```

Afterwards you could create the `List<BigDecimal> dayWiseSales` in one statment:

```
final List<BigDecimal> dayWiseSales = dateBigDecimalMap.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, use LocalDate instead of Date. Then it should be something like this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Invoice> invoices = Arrays.asList(
                new Invoice(LocalDate.now(), BigDecimal.ONE),
                new Invoice(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1), BigDecimal.TEN),
                new Invoice(LocalDate.now(), BigDecimal.TEN)
        );

        Month requiredMonth = LocalDate.now().getMonth();

        Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> invoicesByDate = invoices.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Invoice::getPurchaseDate, // group invoices by Purchase Date
                        Collectors.mapping(Invoice::getPrice,
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));

        System.out.println(invoicesByDate); // {2018-08-28=11, 2018-08-27=10}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the actual structure used in your question you could collect the `BigDecimal` values grouped by day of month in a `Map<Integer, List<BigDecimal>>`.
Then sum them for each entry and collect it into   `Map<Integer, BigDecimal>`.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

// ...

List<Invoice> invoiceListForMonth = ... ;

Map<Integer, BigDecimal> sumByDayOfMonth = 
invoiceListForMonth.stream()
                  .collect(groupingBy(i -> i.getPurchaseDate()
                                            .getDate(),
                                      mapping(Invoice::getPrice, toList())))
                  // Map<Integer, List<BigDecimal>> is produced above
                  .entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue()
                                                              .stream()
                                                              .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)));
```